# Redirection in Windows Server

Tags: redirect, windows, redirection, isapi-rewrite

I do have a similar question [posted on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/254495/76729).

Still, I want to explore various ways by which one can effectively redirect traffic coming to a Windows Server.  Is it possible that I have a `index.php` file but let the URL to it be `index.htm`? On apache, I could do this with mod-rewrite, but I am not sure how to do this on a Windows Server.

I am currently reading about named [a 3rd party module](http://www.isapirewrite.com) `ISAPI_Rewrite`. But has anyone of you come across any similar situation? If yes, can you please show me the way to do it?

Sorry I am a complete noob with Windows Server, so I am going to require a little extra effort from all of you guys.

Answer (score 0):

For redirection of all requests, you can do this in IIS. Runt `inetmgr` in Windows 2008 to open the IIS Manager, and select the web site. Then, in Features View you will see under IIS a button called `HTTP Redirect`.

There is another button for selecting default document, so if you want it to be `index.php`, you can do that here.

For redirecting mobile users, have a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/238706/iis-7-5-redirect-url-rewrite-to-mobile-version-of-website) post about `IIS rewrite rule`.

Comment: I just configured IIS on a Windows XP machine to test things out. I have my mobile device detection mechanism working perfectly, would just want to do the above. I just try your solution out and revert

Answer (score 0):

In ISAPI_Rewrite the following code will create 301-redirect to virtual .html file and rewrite back to .php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule index\.php$ /index.html [NC,R=301,L]
Rewriterule index\.html$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I have found the solution with IIRF. see it here: http://serverfault.com/questions/254495/redirecting-with-web-config/257210#257210